# Я не знаю как это назвать но помогите

Tags: python, python-3.6

От сервера я получаю это

```
Залетайте к нам в беседку 
https://vk.me/join/AJQ1d1lzIBkEtPQT0o41_NVm
```

как мне найти "`https://vk.me/join/`" и если оно есть то вывести всю ссылку целиком?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй RegEx, вот пример:

```
result = re.search(r'https://vk\.me/join/[A-Za-z0-9_]+', src)
print result.group(0)
```

Comment: В некоторых случая после одной фразы идет ище один / и это перестает работать, пример:

`https://vk.me/join/AJQ1d2aIBRkuBo2Y4_KPu/lQ`
`https://vk.me/join/AJQ1d0WwHBixAJjEt/zHkqac`
`https://vk.me/join/AJQ1d/RHlxhVn78lkBfZlDTB `

Comment: Да, совсем забыла, нужный RegEx:
`r'https://vk\.me/join/[A-Za-z0-9_/]+'`